# XAML Control padding overlapping other controls

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I am doing a windows phone app that I have a 6 x 6 grid of checkboxes, They have to be sized specifically to line up with a background image. I can get the content size correct, but the entire size of the control is too big. I am using the default controltemplate, and I have tried to set the padding to alter the padding between the content and the outer margin of the control but it does not change.

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkc1r1" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,24,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="58" Width="42" Tap="chkc1r1_Tap" 
            BorderThickness="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" Padding="-10"/>
```

What am I missing here?

After doing some more digging, I found that the property that I looking for is the touch overhang property, has anyone ever altered this property? A very old post that says it can be done in the App.xaml, but did not say how. Anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! There's no need to include "greetings" or your name in your questions. Your name is displayed at the bottom right anyway. We try to focus on questions and answers, not the jibber jabber around them! ;)

Comment: have you tried editing the default control template? Another option though less clean would likely include using negative margins.

Comment: Yes, I have tried using negative margins, and I know that probably the only way to do it is to edit the control template, but I do not know enough about editing templates to determine what I actually need to change in the template itself I am still playing with it. If anyone knows how I would do this or can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone have any Ideas?

Specify your own control template for your checkboxes. In Blend, right-click on a checkbox, "Edit Template/Edit a copy", save. Then in visual studio edit the template, replacing `"{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}"` with e.g. `"0"`.

Comment: Just wanted to note, this does give me access to the margin and the static resource where I can set to 0 so it does answer my question and I will mark it as the answer but it did not solve my issue, the overall template size for the control resizes the interior controls which what I am trying to avoid. but thanks for the answer it did give me more insight into how the controls are built. I do not have enough reputation to vote your answer up... sorry I am new here.